# passing regular expressions as params into ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, view, parameters

so i would like to expose regular expression queries on a field in my model, such that user could ask for

```
http://localhost:3000/myview.json?field=^hello, (there|world).*
```

so i know i'll have to change my routes to recognise the wildcard characters etc, and i can easily do a `Regexp.new()` inside my controller to convert this to a real regular expression (i'm using mongomapper in the back).

the issue is the potentially huge security hole with XSS.

should i be worried about this? how could i safely enable users to query with regular expression strings.

(i'm not too bothered about the user hammering the database... yet)

Comment: You shouldn't have to change your routes for that (the URL is the same, you're just including params). I also don't understand what the XSS hole is.

Comment: i believe the routes per default will filter out non-`\w+`, so the regex characters won't make it through. my worry about the XSS is that there  one could inject some javascript code into the regex.

Comment: You have to mess around with constraints to get some characters inside routes but you don't need anything special with parameters. You do need to properly URI encode the parameters though.

Comment: It would be better to have the client encode them (e.g. replacing spaces with `%20`) Most (if not all) modern browsers, for example, will do this automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions won't be able to perform arbitrary code execution unless there is something really wrong with `Regexp.new`. So if we assume that `Regexp.new` will either make a valid regular expression or fail or do something else sane you are safe already without having to sanitize the incoming string.